# PHP parsing CSV only returning 1st line

Tags: php, parsing, csv

I'm trying to parse a CSV file in PHP and work with the values, however my code is only returning data from the first line of the CSV file.

The CSV file looks like this

```
C,  QXM0039326, ,           X6, 2288314208
C,  QXP0039226, 7021130,    X6,     100013427
```

The php looks like this:

```
if (($handle = fopen("easy.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",", "\n")) !== FALSE) 
    {
        // do something with the data here
        echo $data[0] . " - ". $data[1] . " - ". $data[2] . "</br>" ;
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
```

This produces the expected results for $data[0] etc, but only the 1st line of the csv.
So I get an output result like this:

```
C - QTM0039326 - 2288314208
```

This is exactly the output that I want, however for every line in the CSV.

I've tried to iterate over the $data like so

```
if (($handle = fopen("easy.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",", "\n")) !== FALSE) 
    {
        // do something with the data here
        foreach ($data as $row){
            echo $row[0] . " - ". $row[1] . " - ". $row[4] . "</br>" ;
    }   
    fclose($handle);
}

}
```

But this gives me a really whack result like this (continuing on):

```
C - - 
Q - T - 0
- - 
X - 6 - 
2 - 2 - 3
```

What do I have to do to get the results I'm after (i.e. C - QTM0039326 - 2288314208 ) but for every line of the CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this one line. May be there is problem with the line break.

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
```

Comment: Although this wasn't the correct answer, it led me to the answer. There was a problem in the CSV and the line break wasn't being recognised. I added a ";" at the end of every line and changed to while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "," ";")) !== FALSE) which worked. Auto detect as in your answer also worked - so now I have to look at the CSV and why it's giving a whack line break.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Youve closed the file handle inside your loop, so there isnt anything on the next iteration....

Should look like:

```
if (($handle = fopen("easy.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",", "\n")) !== FALSE) 
    {
        // do something with the data here
        echo $data[0] . " - ". $data[1] . " - ". $data[2] . "</br>" ;
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: This still only returns the first result. I've edited the question to take the close out of the loop.